# How to call any webservices in phone gap application

Tags: iphone

My application is phonegap template based i am understand about Javascript,CSS,HTML all is fine but i want call any webservices in my javascript code so how can i do if anybody know so please reply me answer to this question

Thank You To ALL

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use [SudzC](http://sudzc.com/)..